# R variables names object

Tags: r, loops, rename

I'm new to R. I want to define urca.adf objects for each variables in my dataset (10 variables), so I tried this code:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   paste0("test.p",i)
   test <- summary(ur.df(data[,i],type="trend",lags=5)
}
```

but I don't know how to write code that allows me to copy (or rename) the object test to test.p1 (.... test.p10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in your loop.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
   paste0("test.p",i)
   test <- summary(ur.df(data[,i],type="trend",lags=5)
   #### this will assign the variable test.p"i" to the value test
   assign(paste("test.p",i,sep=""), test)
}
```

you may later access the variables in this manner.

```
> get("test.p1")
```

or

```
> test.p1
```